# How to implement rdd.bulkSaveToCassandra in datastax

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

- I am using datastax cluster with 5.0.5.

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.11.1485 | DSE 5.0.5 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native proto
```

using spark-cassandra-connector 1.6.8

I tried to implement below code.. import is not working.

```scala
val rdd: RDD[SomeType] = ... // create some RDD to save import
com.datastax.bdp.spark.writer.BulkTableWriter._

rdd.bulkSaveToCassandra(keyspace, table)
```

Can someone suggest me how to implement this code. Are they any dependenceis required for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra Spark Connector has `saveToCassandra` method that could be used like this (taken from [documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/v1.6.8/doc/5_saving.md)):

```
val collection = sc.parallelize(Seq(("cat", 30), ("fox", 40)))
collection.saveToCassandra("test", "words", SomeColumns("word", "count"))
```

There is also `saveAsCassandraTableEx` that allows you to control schema creation, and other things - it's also described in documentation referenced above.

To use them you need to `import com.datastax.spark.connector._` described in "[Connecting to Cassandra](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/v1.6.8/doc/1_connecting.md)" document.

And you need to add corresponding dependency - but this depends on what build system do you use.

The `bulkSaveToCassandra` method is available only when you're using DSE's connector. You need to add corresponding dependencies - see [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkJavaApi.html) for more details. But even [primary developer of Spark connector says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072442/how-to-use-method-bulksavetocassandra-with-spark-cassandra-connector) that it's better use `saveToCassandra` instead of it.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I'm looking for bulkSaveToCassandra APi. Any idea?

Comment: Updated the anser

Comment: Thanks Alex. The reason I am looking is, I ran job using DF.write.format(org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra). it took 36 min for 32 million records. When this method calls, spark stage is idle for ~12 min . I can see logs in driver, "com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector: Disconnected from Cassandra cluster"   Then it's reconnected and started loading. Any idea why its disconnects when loading into cassandra.

Comment: it could be timeout when reading of big chunks of data, or something like.  But without code it's hard to say.

Comment: Please consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem, @Chandra